# Execute a script after copying anything to clipboard

Tags: linux, macos, copy

I want to run a script in the background as soon as something is copied to the clipboard. I want to perform an action based on what is copied to the clipboard.
Are any hooks available for bash/zsh to do this in Linux/mac?

Comment: I understood according to this site [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44204/access-unix-clipboard) you can control clipboard on linux. I don't know if such script exist but you can write this.

Comment: There is no "clipboard" built into Linux, although of course each window manager / desktop manager offers one. You would need to specify at least which GUI you are using.

Comment: @user1934428 it does not have to be any clipboard, if I copy anything I need to run a script. I use mac

Comment: Aren't you contradicting yourself? You are **tagging** your question with Linux, and now you say that you are **using** a Mac. Does it mean that you have installed Linux on the Mac, instead of MacOS?

Comment: Any solution would be fine on Linux or mac?

Comment: this is not a zsh question, it's an os question. your OS (via your WM/GUI) controls the clipboard, and would then run the script (via whatever shell you define in the first line). So it very much matters whether you're on macOS or some type of Linux, and which type, which WM, etc